# Specify Mongo DB and Collection name as variables in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

MongoDB's PHP library allows me to connect to a collection like this ([from example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php)):

```php
$m = new Mongo(); 
$db = $m->comedy; 
$collection = $db->cartoons;
```

But how do I specify the database and/or the collection name as a variable? What I want to do is something like this:

```php
$m = new Mongo();
$dbname = "comedy"; 
$collectionname = "cartoons"; 
$db = $m[$dbname]; 
$collection = $db[$collectionname];
```

I can do this [using the Python API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1.1/tutorial.html), so I find it strange that I am not able to do it using PHP.

UPDATE: This is the error I am getting when I use the above method, which leads me to believe there's no built-in way to address MongoDB collections using variable names?

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Mongo as array
```

ANSWER: As per accepted answer below, this will work:

```php
$db = $m->$dbname; 
$collection = $db->$collectionname;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still get it by a variable using -> ie `$m->$dbname` via http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Comment: Thanks, just edited it. But that didn't fix it - this is the error I get: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Mongo as array"

Comment: You can still get it by a variable using -> ie $m->$dbname via http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Comment: Ah, that did work! Thanks, can you edit/update your answer? Marking this as right?

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for `mongodb` library:

```
$dbname = "comedy";
$collectionname = "cartoons";
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://".$config["MONGO_USER"].":".$config["MONGO_PASS"]."@".$config["MONGO_SERVER"]."/".$dbname))
        ->{$dbname}->{$collectionname};

$insertOneResult = $collection->insertOne([
    'data'=>"my data"
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

That will work with the provision that the "names" used are valid var names in PHP (ex. if you use a space on the "collection" name, it will fail).